# Assembling my first recording package. What to buy?

Tags: portable-recorder, microphone, starter, kit

Hi everyone,
I'm just getting started in the SFX/Foley world and want to assemble my first kit to record in the field and on location. I know I'll need a mic and a portable recorder, but there are just way to many choices for a starter. So, I need some advice which kind of microphone I should get (directional, stereo, condenser, …) and from which brand since I have absolutely no work experience and have no idea which are the better brands. Also I would need a recording device and I have no idea (again :P) what kind I should get (with built-in mic, multitrack, …) and from which company. Also, is there anything else I would need? My budget is about $1400 and it'd be great to get the best out of that. The more specific you will be, the more you will help me.

I'd appreciate any help since I'm a complete newbie. :)

(If this has been asked already, just point me a link to the question since I can't seem to find it.)

Answer (score 2):

Leonard, if you search SSD for "recorder" you will find [all these threads](https://sound.stackexchange.com/search?q=recorder) that should give you a good head start. If you search for "microphone" it'll be a bit less straight-to-the-point but you'll come across [heaps of interesting info on mics](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microphone------) and how people use them.

Now I can give you a few hints -- and I won't be impartial -- but I won't give you the answer, simply because an answer... there is not!

- Ric Viers wrote a book called *The Sound Effects Bible* in which he suggests "starter packs"
- some call the Rode NT1-A the "poor man's U87"
- the Fostex FR2-LE is worth looking at, it does a better job than my Tascam DR-100
- Rode mics are very affordable (compared to other good mics) and do a very good job
- the U87 is used for Foley work -- however doesn't fit your budget, mine either!

Try getting a feel for it, it'll help you take off when you finally put your gear together...

Comment: I would recommend the Zoom H4n over the FR2 if you want to save some cash.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shootout I did recently of a few of the options.

[part 1](http://thesoundmyheadmakes.blogspot.com/2010/11/handheld-recorder-shootout-part-1-specs.html)
[part 2](http://thesoundmyheadmakes.blogspot.com/2010/12/handheld-recorder-shootout-part-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

My gear, very basic but it works.  Don't bother with NTG 1 and 2 isn't that much better.  NTG 3 on the other hand is on par with a 416, but a little more base heavy if i remember correctly.  Go with a zoom H4n.  This is my gear.  I manage in the industry as a location sound recordist fine. http://www.realsound.com.au/?page_id=114  I'll need some more gear if i get some bigger gigs, but for now its pretty good.  Also you don't particularly need the mixer right away.  my gear costed about $3500 Australian Dollars.  the mixer was $800 AUD.